# dbproj : error : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dbproj

When I load up a solution in Visual Studio 2010 that contains a database project, I get this error:

> Loading C:\path\project.dbproj ...
>   C:\path\project.dbproj : error  : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

I've tried devenv.exe /setup but that did not fix it. Does anyone know how to fix this and get database projects to load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reran the Visual Studio install, and now my solution is fine. I didn't uninstall it, just selected Change or Remove Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 opition.

Comment: I tried several other things first but ultimately this was what fixed it.